# How to make iframe content to be indexed as a part of it's parent container?

Tags: javascript, iframe, indexing

I have a website that I update some of it's content on monthly basis.
The content for those pages include tables in iframe format. Now when I search for that particular keyword i see that google is indexing my iframes individually.
Therefore their contents doesn't add any value to the main parent container.Below you'll see one the pages with iframe.

http://www.reguluspc.com/parts/case.html

I want to keep the content intact but keep the table in iframe and update the table only. To avoid duplicated content, I keep the iframe but it doesn't look good as it doesn't have any navigation or proper CSS file.

Any ideas how to make the iframe content to be indexed as part of the main parent page?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

As these are two separate urls, they will be indexed as separate content.

Why are the tables being loaded from iframes? Do you have any server-side languages like PHP, JAVA, .NET, etc? Your might also have `*.shtml` which would allow you to do server side includes for content like that.

Comment: I loaded the table as iframe because it will get new updates and previous content should be deleted but the content of the parent will remain intact.

Comment: I also want to have the content of the old table as archive for SEO.

Initially I was thinking instead of creating iframe, I can keep all the contents on one page but this way, the page become too long and heavy to load on mobile devices and i didn't know how to cope with this issue, so I decided to incorporate iframe which isn't a good solution for SEO as half of my content gets ranked for iframe and half for parent page.